# If $X,Y$ are geometric random variables, and $Z = X+Y$, then what is $P\{X= x, Z=z\}$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> $X,Y$ are independent random variable that follow geometric distribution with parameter $p$. Let Z = $X + Y$,
>   1) What is $P\{X = x, Z = z\}$?

I did this: 
$$P\{X = x, Z = z\}=P\{X = x, Y = z-x\}=P\{X = x\}P\{Y = z-x\}$$
because they are independent. Is it correct?

> 2)What is $P\{X | Z = n\}$?

I did $$P(X=k|Z = n)= P(X=k|Y= n-k),$$ and since they are independent,
$$P(X=k|Y= n-k) = P(X=k)$$
which is still geometric distribution but for $k=0,1,2,...n$ because $k$ can not be more than $n$.
Is it correct?

Please help. Many thanks

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: For 1), correct so far, but you  should express this in terms of $p$. For 2) one should probably compute explicitly, using the ordinary machinery of conditional probabilities. The distribution cannot be geometric, since as you pointed out $k$ cannot be greater than $n$.

Comment: @André Nicolas do you mean the distribution is not geometric? But what distribution is it now? Please help

Comment: You are close to computing the (conditional) probability mass function.   Hint: The dependence on $k$ will disappear!

Answer (score 2):

1) At the moment you just have probability statement. You should provide an actual probability (plug into the pmf).

2) You want to recall that if $X,Y$ are iid, then the sum follows a negative binomial distribution,
$$X+Y\sim \text{NB}(r = 2, p).$$
Further, we have that, assuming the support for $X,Y$ is $\{0,1,2,3,\dotsc\}$,
\begin{align*}
P(X =k|Z = n)&=\frac{P(X = k, Z = n)}{P(Z = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(X = k,Y+X = n)}{P(Y+X = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(Y=n-k|X = k)P(X = k)}{P(X+Y = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(Y = n-k)P(X = k)}{P(X+Y = n)}\tag 1\\
&=\frac{(1-p)^{n-k}p\cdot(1-p)^kp}{\binom{n+2-1}{2-1}(1-p)^np^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is true by independence. We conclude that $X|Z=n$ follows a discrete uniform distribution on $[0,1,\dotsc,n]$.

Comment: The bottom 2 steps confuse me. X ,  Y has geometric distribution, I thought the formula for the mass function is (1-p)^k-1*p? How come your answer is (1-p)^k*p? Also, lots of textbooks use another formula for negative binomial distribution, when I use that formula, the answer is 1/(n-1). I am so confused. Please help！

Comment: If the possible values of $X$ and $Y$ are $\{0,1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, then $P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k} p$. If the possible values are $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, then $P(X = k) = (1-p)^{k-1}p$. Instead of memorizing formulas, you should try to understand what they mean. In the first case, $X$ counts the number of failures until the first success; in the second, it counts the number of trials.

Comment: The same can be said about the negative binomial distribution.

Comment: Are you telling me you and me are perfect match? Are you telling me you are from UCB?